# So what happens/is going to happen/will happen is one of two things

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

*We have your house surrounded. You can't escape. So **what happens/is going to happen/will happen** is one of two things. Either you come out here with your hands up or we're going to come in there and drag you out ourselves.*

What is the natural way to phrase this?

Answer (score 1):

All three are OK. I prefer "will happen". I think "is going to happen" is clumsy. Just plain "happens" is not quite grammatical, but it's what a tough cop might say, particularly in a novel or film.

The second sentence might then say "we come in there ..." rather than "we're going to come in there ...".